# htaccess with dynamic parameters causing redirect loop

Tags: .htaccess

I have checked for duplicate question, but the answers there are for different issues. I'm trying to get the following to work; the first part works OK

```
RewriteEngine On

# for external redirection from `/home.php?su=sitename` to `/sitename`
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+home\.php\?su=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1? [R=301,L]

# for internal redirection from `/sitename` to `/home.php?su=sitename`
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /home.php?su=$1 [L,QSA]
# --------------------------------
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/pagenew2\.php\?su=([^\s&]+)&PgID=(\d+)&pu=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(\d+)/([^/]+)\.html$ /pagenew2.php?su=$1&PgID=$2&pu=$3 [L,QSA]
```

However, the 2nd one (below the line I've added here, pagenew2) redirects OK - but the page never opens and you get a 'redirect loop' error.

Any help gratefully accepted - I'm completely in the dark when it comes to things like this!

Comment: do you have any other rules?

Comment: Thanks Starkeen - no other rules

Comment: I dont think your code is causing a redirect loop error.

Comment: That's why I'm trying to find the answer! What in the code is causing the loop?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry - I misread your answer about 'don't' think it's in the code - and you are correct.

There was a line about header location (something else I'd tried) which I thought was commented out, but once removed completely, the redirect works properly.
Thanks
Chris